# How to change actionbar like gmail

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to create a actionbar, let it like gmail's actionbar.
In other words,
When the item is selected in listView, actionbar's logo will change to the Cancel button.
Does this have to custom actionbar's layout?
[image]

or , it is not a actionbar ,it's a Contextual Menus?

Comment: yes, it is contextual menu http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu

Comment: thank you Selvin, 
ok, it's a contextual menu. could i wait it up by code?

Comment: in other words,wake it up like gallery's behavior. menu -> select -> show contextual menu .

Comment: https://plus.google.com/113735310430199015092/posts/R49wVvcDoEW

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for you link,but what you want to say?

Comment: @GeminiYellow: I was pointing out a Googler who published an implementation of the DONE+DISCARD pattern, and that implementation may be useful in helping you work out how to implement what you are seeking.

Comment: @CommonsWare oh yes,thanks CommonsWare,it's useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks @Selvin and @CommonsWare 
it's a context-menu, `ListView` or `RecyclerView`, and you can just call [`startActionMode()`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB) to start it (API 11 or later).

But in `startActionMode()`, it will not call `onItemCheckedStateChanged`,
you must implement a click listener from the adapter by yourself.